# Firebasemessaging & Firebasedatabase in the same class crashing application at startup?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Have anyone succeeded using firebasedatabase & firebasemessaging in the same activity ? I've got two projects working in standalone, but as soon as i add a `DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();` in the `MainActivity` (of the project already instantiating firebasemessaging), my application is crashing at startup.

I've looked on the web and could not find any hints...:(

Here is the main activity code:

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java;

    import -> all imports removed for smaller post.

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        final DatabaseReference ring = myRef.child("mykey");

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting MainActivity...");


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Log.d(TAG, "HERE???...");
                // Create channel to show notifications.
                String channelId  = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
                String channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH));
            }

            /// subscribing by default to all channel.
            Log.d(TAG, "Subscribing to all topic...");
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");


            // Handle possible data accompanying notification message.
            // [START handle_data_extras]
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                    Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                }
            }
            // [END handle_data_extras]

            Button subscribeButton = findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
            subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Subscribing to all topic");
                    // [START subscribe_topics]
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all")
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
                                    }
                                    Log.d(TAG, msg);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                    // [END subscribe_topics]
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

in the logCat i get:

> 2019-07-10 01:04:03.139 1364-3739/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/.java.MainActivity bnds=[32,1101][235,1410]} from uid 10072 pid 22480
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.144 603-603/? W/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.iop@2.0::IIop/default in either framework or device manifest.
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.144 1364-3739/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: Iop tryGetService failed
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.150 1364-3739/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: Activity is Triggerred in full screen ApplicationInfo{a048f56 com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm}
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.150 1364-3739/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java.MainActivity/1
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.150 1364-3739/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{a048f56 com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.150 1364-3739/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java.MainActivity/1
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.150 1364-3739/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.153 22480-22480/? D/BaseDraggingActivity: startActivity bookkeeping intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/.java.MainActivity bnds=[32,1101][235,1410] }
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.153 22480-22480/? D/Stats: Intent.getPackage() is null. therefore try to get package name from componentName.getPackageName(): com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.154 22480-22480/? D/Stats: Intent.getPackage() is null. therefore try to get package name from componentName.getPackageName(): com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.154 22480-25599/? D/Stats: save stats in background ...
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.154 22480-22480/? D/ItemClickHandler: onClick app, tag = AppInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=-1 screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Firebase Cloud Messaging hidden=false dirty = false newInstallTag=null componentName=ComponentInfo{com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java.MainActivity} searchResult=null suggestionApp=null)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.154 22480-25599/? D/GridItemProvider: saveStatToFile: package %s is not installed. Skip it.ComponentInfo{com.microsoft.office.outlook/com.microsoft.office.outlook.MainActivity}
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.155 22480-22480/? D/Launcher: onPause# hashcode: 22657230
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.156 22480-11989/? V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 8506
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.156 22480-11989/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.157 22480-22507/? I/WeatherProvider: un-subscribe the weather callback: 
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.157 1364-3744/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{a048f56 com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.157 1364-3744/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java.MainActivity/1
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.158 1364-1411/? D/RestartProcessManager: Update Total Launch Times :com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.158 1364-1411/? D/RestartProcessManager: updateSelf :  com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm, size : 30
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.158 1364-1411/? D/RestartProcessManager: Increase Total Launch Time : com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm, times : 6, index : 29
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.158 1364-1411/? D/RestartProcessManager: Last Running Package : com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm , start time 1562713443158
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.158 22480-11989/? V/FA: Activity paused, time: 45839580
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.159 22480-11989/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=8506, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Launcher, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8729914221436155707}]
>       ....
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 1364-1364/? V/SettingsProvider: Notifying for 0: content://settings/system/game_mode_status_auto
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.AuthTokenProvider com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService) (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at void com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider() (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at void com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices() (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at void com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze() (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase.database.core.Context, com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoInfo, com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase) (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase.database.core.Context, com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoInfo, com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase) (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at void com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo() (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference() (com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:188)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at void com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.java.MainActivity.() (MainActivity.java:58)
>       2019-07-10 01:04:03.661 12098-12098/? I/.quickstart.fc:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance() (Class.java:-2)

Comment: Could you provide which version you used? Providing `buidld.gradle` codes will helps answerers.

Comment: Hello Galcyurio, sure, here you go:

Comment: Hello Galcyurio, 
I won't need to. Thanks to your question i could see that there was a version that could be upgraded.
I was using:   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4' 
Upgraded it to the proposed latest    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0' 
And... bingo it's now working.. 

Thanks so much for your help ! I can have both messaging & database working in the same class...

appreciate it.
fab

Comment: in case someone else get the issue...here are my working gradle files
App build.gradle:
`    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' `

Comment: ` Module app build.gradle:
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4' changed into -> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0' `

Comment: and i appologize for the formatting... tried `code` didn't work... sorry.

Comment: Good. You can answer your question. It will help people who have experienced issues like you.